# Javascript property not being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and this is driving me nuts.

I'm trying to update an object that comes from state

```
var state = this.state;

sku = data['sku'];
console.log(sku) //prints sku/06
console.log(state.sku) //prints sku/06
state.sku = sku;
console.log(state.sku) //prints sku/10
```

I've checked, and there's only one call being made. Although I'm using flux to update stores, this attribution is made before the action being sent to the dispatcher.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried updating the state using React's `setState` function?

```
var sku = data['sku'];
this.setState({sku: sku});
```

*Directly copied from the React docs [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html_)*

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.
>
> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.
>   setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: This was part of the problem. I could not set state in that point, so I had to find an alternative way. I'm ware that it's not safe to manipulate the state directly. And I thought I wasn't, which, was not the case. I just endend up using lodash cloneDeep `var state = _cloneDeep(this.state)` and everything went as expected then. Thank you!